# i want to store image in postresql using C#

Tags: c#, postgresql

I am trying to store image in bytea data type but it only storing the `Id` number. in `Id` column, I want to store image bytes as well please suggest me some c# code to solve this problem.

Comment: have you insert image to your `bytea` column ??

Comment: What you have tried?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Have you tried searching in google? Can you tell us what have you done till now?

Answer (score 0):

Am using following code to insert image to PostgreSQL database uisng *vb.net*

```
Using pgFileStream As FileStream = New FileStream(productImageFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
     Using pgReader As BinaryReader = New BinaryReader(New BufferedStream(pgFileStream))
        Dim ImgByteA As Byte() = pgReader.ReadBytes(CInt(pgFileStream.Length))
        command.CommandText = "insert into gtab82 (photo)   VALUES  ( @Image)"
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Image", ImgByteA)
        command.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
End Using
```

and following code is used to get the inserted image and displaying it in a *picturebox* control(`PPicBoxPhoto`)

```
 command.CommandText = "select photo from mytable where id=1"
 Try
    Dim productImageByte As Byte() = TryCast(command.ExecuteScalar, Byte())
    If productImageByte IsNot Nothing Then
    Using productImageStream As Stream = New System.IO.MemoryStream(productImageByte)
        PPicBoxPhoto.Image = Image.FromStream(productImageStream)
    End Using
    End If
Catch
    Throw
End Try
```

Online converter [VB TO C#](http://converter.telerik.com/)

Comment: @RajendraSingh Accept the answer(click on the tick symbol )